# SQL STUFF() with UNION Query returning NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

I have a SQL Server 2012 query that is returning 1 row of data , BUT could return multiple rows, based on the query.

I want to turn the following data into a csv concatenated string. My query uses `STUFF()` with a `UNION` query which I based off [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165486/using-union-all-in-stuff-xml-path).

i.e: my data would be this

```
MR
------
NS
------
```

and would become:

```
MR, NS
```

When I select the data without the `STUFF()` part of the query, it returns data no problem.

The full query (see below) runs without errors but always returns `NULL` even though the `SELECT UNION` part of the query returns data.

My full query looks like this:

```
SELECT STUFF((Select * FROM (
SELECT ISNULL(scddisc.abbrev, '!!') AS medicalDisciplines
FROM personenc INNER JOIN contacts ON personenc.cntid = contacts.cntid INNER JOIN scddisc ON contacts.discipline = scddisc.disid
WHERE (personenc.perid = 15410) AND (scddisc.active = 1) AND (contacts.active = 1) AND (scddisc.medgroup = 1) --AND (personenc.sdate BETWEEN '2014-03-05' AND '2014-03-12')
UNION 
SELECT ISNULL(scddisc.abbrev, '!!') AS medicalDisciplines
FROM scddisc INNER JOIN contacts ON scddisc.disid = contacts.discipline INNER JOIN personenc ON contacts.cntid = personenc.ocntid
WHERE (personenc.perid = 15410) AND (scddisc.active = 1) AND (contacts.active = 1) AND (scddisc.medgroup = 1) -- AND (personenc.sdate BETWEEN '2014-03-05' AND '2014-03-12')
) AS k
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')
```

Can anyone let me know what I have done wrong?

The query that works is the `SELECT UNION` part of the above query
i.e. when I run the query below it returns valid data.

```
SELECT ISNULL(scddisc.abbrev, '!!') AS medicalDisciplines
    FROM personenc INNER JOIN contacts ON personenc.cntid = contacts.cntid INNER JOIN scddisc ON contacts.discipline = scddisc.disid
    WHERE (personenc.perid = 15410) AND (scddisc.active = 1) AND (contacts.active = 1) AND (scddisc.medgroup = 1) --AND (personenc.sdate BETWEEN '2014-03-05' AND '2014-03-12')
    UNION 
    SELECT ISNULL(scddisc.abbrev, '!!') AS medicalDisciplines
    FROM scddisc INNER JOIN contacts ON scddisc.disid = contacts.discipline INNER JOIN personenc ON contacts.cntid = personenc.ocntid
    WHERE (personenc.perid = 15410) AND (scddisc.active = 1) AND (contacts.active = 1) AND (scddisc.medgroup = 1) -- AND (personenc.sdate BETWEEN '2014-03-05' AND '2014-03-12')
```

However when combined with the `FOR XML` and `STUFF`, then the full statement return `NULL`

Comment: It's not `STUFF` that does concatenation. It's `FOR XML PATH('')`. Can you show the query that works?

Comment: Have added the select query that works... it is basically the SELECT UNION part of the full query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough I have found the issue. It appears to be 2 fold...

- It appears that the `.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')`
  part of the `STUFF` query was the part that was not displaying data.

  When I change the `text()` to a `.` i.e.
  `.value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')` the query returns as
  expected.
- Secondly I had forgotten to add the `N', ' +` to the `ISNULL(scddisc.abbrev, '!!') AS medicalDisciplines` to make it a comma separated list as required.

Therefore the whole new statement became:

```
SELECT
    STUFF (
        (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        N', ' + ISNULL(scddisc.abbrev, '!!') AS medicalDisciplines
                    FROM
                        personenc
                    INNER JOIN contacts ON personenc.cntid = contacts.cntid
                    INNER JOIN scddisc ON contacts.discipline = scddisc.disid
                    WHERE
                        (personenc.perid = 15410)
                    AND (scddisc.active = 1)
                    AND (contacts.active = 1)
                    AND (scddisc.medgroup = 1) --
                    AND (
                        personenc.sdate BETWEEN '2014-03-05'
                        AND '2014-03-12'
                    )
                    UNION
                        SELECT
                            N', ' + ISNULL(scddisc.abbrev, '!!') AS medicalDisciplines
                        FROM
                            scddisc
                        INNER JOIN contacts ON scddisc.disid = contacts.discipline
                        INNER JOIN personenc ON contacts.cntid = personenc.ocntid
                        WHERE
                            (personenc.perid = 15410)
                        AND (scddisc.active = 1)
                        AND (contacts.active = 1)
                        AND (scddisc.medgroup = 1) -- AND (personenc.sdate BETWEEN '2014-03-05' AND '2014-03-12')
                ) AS k FOR XML PATH (''),
                TYPE ).
            VALUE
                ('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
                1,
                2,
                ''
        );
```

Can anyone tell me what the meaning/difference of `.value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')` and `.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')` is??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STUFF (
(SELECT ... FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')
```

Comment: How does this help? What is it doing?

Comment: This does not help me... That is what my above query is doing... I want to know why I would be getting NULL from the STUFF() & FOR XML when I combine it with the UNION query.

My Full query in my question is returning NULL however the SELECT UNION query is returning data when I run it outside of the STUFF() and FOR XML()